# Ajax POST with jQuery throwing empty errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to fix the following, simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#login").click(function()
    {
        var a = 3;
        var b = 2;
        var dataString = "a="+a+"&b="+b;
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache:"false",
                    beforeSend: function(){console.log("Sending...");},
                    error: function(x,y,z){console.log("err: "+x+" "+y+" "+z);},
            success: function(x,y,z){console.log("succ: "+x+" "+y+" "+z);}
                });
    });
});
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];

echo $a+$b;
?>
```

My problem is that, the site always returns with error and emtpy x,y,z.

Comment: Anything strange when if you check the Network tab? You can look at the status and response there

Comment: if the response is empty, it is most likely an issue before this code is run, what is output in the console? Is your sending... message being printed?

Comment: Verify whether the server is able to process the post request correctly. It is certainly not returning a `200`. Your problems lies there. Add details from the communication for further help.

Comment: There is nothing interesting on the network tab, it seems ok. The output is the dataString, the beforeSend functions text (Sending...) and the error: "err: [object Object] error ".

Comment: well, you're attempting to do a `POST` request, but your "datastring" is a query which should be passed as part of a `GET` request. The data property should instead be an object of the type `{'a':a, 'b':b}` which then ends up in `$_POST` in the PHP script recieving it.

Comment: expand the error object, that might give you more info (click the carat next to it in the console)

Comment: Edit error as following: `error: function(x,y,z){console.log("err: ",x,y,z);},` then you can expand it

Comment: @Tularis datastring also accepted as string also, not only as object.

Comment: good point @TamásSzabó, I was not aware that it converted the object to a string by default (which is weird IMO, but still)... Anyway, the parameters are still comming in `$_GET` instead of post as a query. So checking `$_POST` in PHP still won't get the actual values expected ;)

Comment: @Tularis No, if you set type to post, and pass data, then it will be posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#login").click(function()
        {
            var a = 3;
            var b = 2;
            var dataString:={a:a,b:b};
            $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: dataString,
                    success:function(result)                 {
result=jQuery.parseJSON(result);
console.log("OurResult:"+result );
                        }
                    });
        });
    });
```

now the php part:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$table=array($a,$b);
echo json_encode($table);
?>
```